# How to flatten multiple row values into concatenated string in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple set of three tables . 2 "source" tables and a "join" table that allows one to many relationship.

I have this query:

```
          select data.mph1.data ->> 'name' as name, data.mph1.data ->> 'tags' as Tags, 
          data.mph2.data ->> 'School' as school from data.mph1 
          join data.mph1tomph2 on data.mph1tomph2.mph1 = data.mph1.id
          join data.mph2 on data.mph2.id = data.mph1tomph2.mph2
```

The output appears as:

```
            Name             Tags                                School
           "Steve Jones"    "["tag1", "tag2"]"                  "UMass"
           "Steve Jones"    "["tag1", "tag2"]"                  "Harvard"
           "Gary Summers"   "["java", "postgres", "flutter"]"   "Yale"
           "Gary Summers"   "["java", "postgres", "flutter"]"   "Harvard"
           "Gary Summers"   "["java", "postgres", "flutter"]"   "UMass"
```

What I'm looking for is

```
            Name             Tags                               School
           "Steve Jones"    "["tag1", "tag2"]"                  "UMass", "Harvard"
           "Gary Summers"   "["java", "postgres", "flutter"]"   "Yale, Harvard, UMass"
```

How would I get this result in single query? Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select 
    data.mph1.data ->> 'name' as name, 
    data.mph1.data ->> 'tags' as tags, 
    string_agg(data.mph2.data ->> 'School', ', ') as school
from data.mph1 
join data.mph1tomph2 on data.mph1tomph2.mph1 = data.mph1.id
join data.mph2 on data.mph2.id = data.mph1tomph2.mph2
group by data.mph1.id  -- if id is a primary key
-- group by 1, 2       -- otherwise
```

Comment: another quick question. If the root table (data.mph1) had another multi-join to another table (data.someothertable) via another join table (data.mph1tosomeothertable), could I use string_agg() to create a list of those values as a new column?

Comment: Basically yes but the matter is more complex than it may seems. You should join the other table to already aggregated data. If this is not clear for you ask a new question (a full answer is too broad for a comment).

Comment: I am at the early stages of db design for new app, which requires support for extreme dynamic data structure. Based on your deep expertise, I'm wondering if you'd be open to paid session of db architecture review? we are struggling to figure out best way to model for such dynamic data. Would think 1-2 hours would be all that is needed to get guidance on direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't find time. Currently I'm also  struggling with a project and look here for a change.

Comment: undertand, thx for replying. In regards to my question above, generally speaking, if a given table has N number of external multi-value joins like the example I provided, is it possible to dynamically construct a single query to returned those "N" attributes in a separate column with concatenated values? Would love to see the syntax for that.